# Reach out to E107 about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, outsourcing

I think someone at Stack Exchange needs to reachout to [E107](http://e107.org/community) - they say they want to use Stack Overflow as a support site without clear guidance. We have questions that get put on hold and bad questions from them tagged as [e107](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e107).

Could someone make that happen?

#### Full Text from E107

> ## Getting Support
>
> Having trouble getting e107 up and running? Something not working the way you think it should? Unfortunately we don't have time to maintain a full e107 support community ourselves, but there are a few ways to get help.
>
> - If you think you have found a bug, then please see the section below on Reporting Bugs.
> - If you need help with how to use e107 or a development question (such as how to create a theme or plugin) - please see our [docs](http://e107.org/developer-manual), or post a question at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e107) with the tag 'e107'.

Comment: But I'm not a question. I'm a human being.

Comment: Their spelling "Stack Overflow" correctly would be a good start.

Comment: All the questions tagged e107 have negative votes... impressive.

Comment: @Raedwald and not a single answer has an upvote either.

Comment: And almost all of them are off-topic and should be closed/migrated/deleted.

Comment: Maybe they just found out new philosophy: "We can cut support costs. There are other stupid, naive morons, wiling to do the bad job for us" (of course, I'm not willing to offend anyone _here_)?

Comment: Should someone ( perhaps @TimPost ) reach out to FineUploader, see the second comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365192/add-fineuploader-upload-button-after-initializing . Their support page has similar wording to that in psubsee2003's answer, see http://fineuploader.com/support.html

Comment: @AdrianHHH at least its better there than the e107 people.

Comment: Is my comment above the best way of reporting this which appears to be another example of the same question? Or should I have opened a new question?

Comment: @AdrianHHH i would open another question.

Comment: Paypal also says a similar thing in their developer area.

Comment: in regards to @Chris https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support

Comment: @TimPost Paypal actually calls it "**Our** PayPal forum", and they misuse the Stack Overflow name. Follow their link, and lol at everything about the top-voted question in the tag.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yeah, I .. really need to get the help center guidance back in place, I'm going to make that a priority for this week. A *very* common mistake is not pointing people to our guidance for what's on topic, not telling them to also include a language tag, and failing to mention that we're an entirely community-moderated site (which can artificially inflate folks' expectations making the down-votes sting a bit more).

I [reached out to them](https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/480334501755633665) and will continue to try and find the folks that maintain the page, and offer to give them some better copy to put there.

**Update**

They've replied, and they're working on the copy changes now. I've also got our help center copy just about ready to fly, which I'll have in place this week.

Comment: I was really surprised to see that in `e107` support page they directly mention about SO for getting help to users. Are they really allowed to do so (even though it's a open source product)?

Comment: @Rahul there are [things that work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/product-support-redirects-to-stack-overflow) and [things that didn't go well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121547/is-it-time-to-re-evaluate-the-facebook-stack-overflow-partnership) but I don't believe it has even been forbidden to do: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project

Comment: @rene, never knew this. Interesting!

Comment: @Rahul It's best if this sort of happens organically, the developers just see folks coming here, and they pitch in to help answer and help their users have a good experience. That said, it can be orchestrated, but there's some key steps to getting it right. I'll have some _much_ updated guidance (which ends in contacting the community team if at all unsure) in the help center early next week. Should have been done weeks ago but got bumped due to more pressing things.

Comment: Email sent, they were _extremely_ responsive on Twitter so I'm sure we'll get everything sorted out. Looks like an increasingly popular platform, I also invited them to propose a site for it so they have a good place for the general support questions. Tridion, Expression Engine and others have done the same and they're _killing it_ in participation, so I'm hoping this turns into a major positive.

Comment: Any news about this? They still seem to have the unqualified suggestion to come here and there are still bad questions appearing, though it's only a trickle.

Comment: Tim, any chance you can take a look at http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6434/9517 and the related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234700/reach-out-to-generation-d-systems-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-serverfault - hugs ;)

Comment: and now http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6436/9517

Answer (score 18):

It appears that they have already receive negative feedback from their users.  I found a [blog post on their site](http://e107.org/blog/week-1-of-e107-v2-bootstrap-the-work-continues.html) in which the talk about the moving of support to Stack Overflow.

2 excerpts I thought were interesting:

> ### Our top priority is making your feedback actionable, quicker.
>
> We know some of you are concerned about our decision to stop using a bulletin board as the main platform for channelling community feedback and fielding support queries. As a team, we really have spent a lot of time reviewing what the e107 core team should commit to delivering for the community moving forward without promising things it doesn’t have the capacity to provide.
>
> This informed the decision to reposition e107.org to become the platform to grab e107, get the latest development news, showcase what it can do, and inspire users to download it.
>
> It is also the hub pointing you to the other externally-hosted websites for technical development (GitHub), support (StackOverflow), and community banter (Facebook, Twitter).
>
> For the team delivering e107, our top priority is to ensure that bugs and feedback can be channelled in a way that allows a small volunteer development team [we're less than 10 people!] to prioritise issues raised and process them more quickly. We have found GitHub to be a tremendous platform for this. It allows us to work directly with you when you encounter bugs in a way that simply wasn’t possible on the forums. Check it out, you can see a lot of user-raised issues are getting responses directly from our main contributors, including the project founders!
>
> Also, if you've got coding skills, we're in need of your help, so don't hesitate to contribute and join the development team on GitHub to accelerate the development process!

And

> ### The new support infrastructure – it’s a work in progress!
>
> We wanted to thank users who have bravely started using StackOverflow and GitHub as the new platforms to ask for peer-to-peer assistance. We were shocked to hear that users were having trouble posting on StackOverflow because you lacked the necessary reputation points to do so. We’ve run some tests to understand why users haven’t been able to post to StackOverflow. Our tests have identified that users had forgotten to tag their questions to “e107”. If you use the e107 tag you do not need a high reputation score to post a question or to receive a response. So please make sure to do that beforehand, and you shouldn’t experience any more problems raising issues!
>
> StackOverflow offers a pretty good tour to use to get familiarised with the platform. [Check it out here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
>
> These difficulties have nonetheless led us to put the infrastructure under further review. We’ve decided to give StackOverflow a trial period of 3 months to see how it pans out for the community, if we can see that there are just too many issues, we’ll be approaching some e107 community leaders to look at other ways in which peer-to-peer support can be provided away from the main e107.org presence.

Reading through both tells me that they were completely unprepared for the danger of shutting down their user support in exchange for Stack Overflow.  I find it humourous though that they want to blame it on mistagging and not the fact that the questions they are sending to Stack Overflow might be off-topic.

Comment: I think the "having trouble posting on StackOverflow because you lacked the necessary reputation" might refer to posting comments.  So they might also see SO as a forum.  Their "guy" tested posting and had no trouble but their users are probably trying to chat-in-comments and cant.

Comment: @Plutonix good catch, that hadn't crossed my mind.  Given the tagging solution they suggested, I was guessing the "couldn't post" meant questions were getting closed.

Comment: "Our tests have identified that users had forgotten to tag their questions to “e107”. If you use the e107 tag you do not need a high reputation score to post a question or to receive a response." What they are talking about? A tag surely doesn't change a users privileges.

Comment: @Wumm that's why I think the issue with asking is closing and not actually privileges. They think the tag with magically keep the question open.

Comment: *"We've decided to give StackOverflow a trial period .."* is pretty funny. As if SO went knocking on their door hat in hand and asked if they could graciously move the support here. "Well all right, but you better make it worth it! We'll be monitoring you!"

Comment: @wumm I think their users are likely complaining about posting **comments**.  So, their guy went to SO either with low rep or a new account and found he **could** post a question using the [e107] tag. His conclusion is that you can post using [e107] tag, which is correct without being accurate.  Its like concluding that the turbulence you feel on a plane just after they ask you to buckle your seat belts is **caused by** fastening your seat belts.

Comment: The phrasing of these blog posts makes it pretty clear they expect Stack Overflow to work like a forum.

Comment: @Juhana Others [also gave SO "trial periods"](http://www.openxava.org/en/blog/moving-support-to-stackoverflow), and say `XXXX close valid questions, and we think this is unacceptable`. The amusing part is the trial period duration they give SO is almost consistent at _3 months_ :-)