# Reach out to Intuit about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Intuit isn't giving much [guidance](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support) on what questions are appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Relevant snip:

> ### Ask a Question
>
> - Stack Overflow—Community for technical questions and
>   answers
> - Live Community Forum—Community for non technical and technical
>   discussions

They are using [intuit-partner-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit-partner-platform)

Comment: At least they aren't linking to the "Ask Question" page with some tags prefilled.

Comment: @ChrisF who's doing that?

Comment: There's plenty of guidance in the Help Center, for anyone who bothers to read it.  I don't get the impression that Intuit is listing Stack Overflow as their sole support resource; quite the contrary.  It's more like a "you can ask a question here" link.

Comment: @DanielA.White - nobody right now - but it has been known to happen.

Comment: It's definitely better than some company's links to here are, but it could be nuanced a little to save us some aggravation here or there, maybe.

Comment: [Jarred Keneally](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1069359/jarred-keneally) and [Peter Lavelle](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1698450/peter-lavelle) look like good people to reach out to.

Comment: I see no issue with their recommendation to use StackOverflow. The tag is linked.

Comment: Just curious ... Is there any specific reason they don't want to keep a in-house technical forum and redirecting to SO? I believe it's probably cause of budget issue ... right?

Comment: @staticx the problem is that they don't give any guidance on how to ask.

Comment: @DanielAWhite: Seems like a problem for them. Not a StackOverflow problem. If they don't provide guidance, not sure why we should care. It's their responsibility to monitor the right tags and tell people to tag properly to get their issue seen

Comment: @staticx it's not that they don't monitor it. It's a pattern that can create poorly written questions

Comment: I think it's still mixing two different things. The community will deal with questions and answers. New users are prompted and there are algorithms to check for low quality answers and questions. I don't think Inuit needs to direct their users to a tutorial when its already apparent on StackOverflow

Comment: @rahul: probably they recognize SO's format is better for programming Q&A than a forum. Google did the same thing with App Engine years ago, and I can't imagine having a Google Groups mailing list before they moved programming support here was breaking the bank.

Comment: @Wooble, I can understand that SO is the best place to get an answer... was just curious. Tell me one more thing ... did Google paid any amount to SO for that (OR) free of cost. If free ... then Man! they are saving a lot probably :)

Comment: I doubt the marginal savings of one less google group being active are even measurable. Storing my Spam folder probably costs them more.

Comment: There is a discussion of this general issue here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394/157957 It's been coming up a lot recently, and [Tim Post is putting together some official guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261202/157957).

Comment: @ChrisF: oh well, about the "nobody right now" ... http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261678/

Answer (score 10):

This is similar to [surveymonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surveymonkey), which works well on SO. They suggest people answer questions on SO and their developers monitor the tag and answer most of the questions.

[They say more or less the same thing](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/), with [a link to the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=surveymonkey):

[image]

[OpenFDA](https://open.fda.gov/) did the same thing with the [openfda tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openfda) on [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/), and it works well there, too. The [link directly to the ask screen](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=openFDA) from their sidebar:

[image]

I don't see any problem with this.

Comment: How do they suggest it on their sites?

Comment: @DanielA.White Added links and screenshots.

Comment: It can be a problem if they refer to it as a forum.

Comment: Of course, the FDA linking led to this question which is more ephemeral : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/3276/263 .  (and as a moderator on OpenData.SE, I want to close it after they've fixed the issue, but then we lose that we've got the registered name of who's dealing w/ issues there)