# Reach out to Apigee about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

Apigee has [some guidance](http://community.apigee.com/content/apigee-customer-support) to put questions under the [apigee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apigee), but they don't state how to ask exactly. I've seen some bad questions being posted in the tag.

> ### Using the free Apigee Developer service?
>
> The *main source of support for our developer community is through
> Stackoverflow*.  Apigee experts around the world actively monitor
> questions tagged "apigee". Response time is fast and comes from
> experienced users that are used to solving hard problems. Review our
> answered questions or post your own question.
>
> If you're having a problem with your account or have a question that
> can't be asked in a public forum, you can email us at help@apigee.com.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: It's not a good start when they can't get the name of the site right :(

Comment: @ChrisF: sure, shame on them for looking at the icon on the page and being as bad as the Denver offices. :P

Comment: What's with all the recent "out-reaching"? Must be charity week or something...

Comment: @Sam i've been seeing bad questions creep up. i hope if we can get things clarified, things might improve.

Comment: @Sam OP has brought up nearly (if not all) of the outsourcing issues on meta in the last week. Definitely an issue, so much so that the help documentation was written swiftly.

Comment: I'm not criticizing anyone, I'm just stating my observations (that there have been a sudden influx of "reach out"s recently).

Comment: There's a lot of downvoted questions in that tag.  If Apigee wants to offload their customer support to Stack Overflow, the least they can do is warn people that not all of their questions are going to get answered here.  Related: [Why We're Not Customer Support for Your Favorite Company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/102937)

Comment: Hey, @ChrisF, they've [linked to the Ask Question page with their tag](http://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2fask%3ftags%3dapigee). :)

Comment: Related: [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394/119527)

Comment: Maybe we should catch the uri they are using for the ask question link, and then educate the users about how we are not the support etc. but since we are nice people if they can formulate something ontopic we allow it

Comment: Has outsourced support at SO *ever* worked? It was pretty disastrous when Facebook tried it. I tend to think SO is at its best as a *supplement* to in-house support, not a *replacement* for it.

Comment: @ChrisF Hmm, what's wrong with it? Seems to be spelled right.

Comment: @NewWorld there's a missing space and capital "O".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am affiliated with Apigee.  Apigee has every intention of being an upstanding member of the Stack Overflow community.  Our intent is to use Stack Overflow as a resource for technical questions that a number of community members may have.  Apigee does no promotion of its products via Stack Overflow nor do we use it for bug reporting or feature enhancement requests.  However, we very much recognize the concerns being raised and will be taking steps to address them.  Thank you for your feedback.

Update: We have made changes to our product support page that were based on examples of appropriate usage of Stack Overflow (http://community.apigee.com/content/apigee-customer-support).  We are now more clear on which questions should go to Stack Overflow.  In particular, we are requesting that "how-to" questions be posted there.  We are also clear that questions must meet the standards for Stack Overflow in order to be answered (and we provide a link to the help page for that).  So, there should not be any expectation for an answer if it doesn't follow the guidelines.

All links on our site were updated to point to this page before going to Stack Overflow.  So going forward there should not be anyone posting to Stack Overflow without seeing the revised page.

We hope these changes show that we take your feedback quite seriously.  We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused.

Comment: Thanks Mike for responding. That is all I hope for. :)

Comment: The fact that you've written the name "Stack Overflow" correctly is in itself a *great* start (only half-serious of course). Welcome to the site!

Comment: So far, this sounds like a perfectly courteous and beautifully vacuous manager response. I appreciate your engagement, but I would be even happier to see concrete steps you are taking and what changes you are making. Stack Overflow is what it is because of our very specific expectations and requirements. What can you do for us to add value for our community, and how are you making sure not to DOS us by sending a deluge of poorly researched novice questions our way?

Comment: @KerrekSB Considering he answered this on a Saturday I would imagine they haven't even really had a chance to discuss it internally yet.

Comment: From my (not very long) experience such "partnerships" lead only to a flood of poor questions.

Answer (score 41):

Letter I plan to send to Apigee, when I can find an appropriate email address:

> I am a moderator at Stack Overflow, which is to say that, although I
>   am not affiliated with Stack Exchange in any way, I do clean up after
>   the messes that people leave on the site.
>
> One especially significant source of messes are companies that give
>   the impression that they can obtain support for company products at
>   Stack Overflow, or that Stack Overflow is somehow affiliated with
>   companies providing product support.  For the most part, they can't,
>   and they aren't.
>
> Stack Overflow has very specific rules about what kinds of questions
>   can be asked there.  Questions which do not meet those rules are "put
>   on hold" until they meet the site guidelines.  When a user is given
>   the impression that they can obtain product support at Stack Overflow
>   and is rebuffed, that leaves a bad impression on everyone, including
>   your company.
>
> Especially problematic is the link that you have provided to the Ask A
>   Question page with an automatic [apigee] tag.  This link completely
>   bypasses the Help Center, where users are provided with the site
>   guidelines.  This contributes to the problem of users asking off-topic
>   questions.
>
> Finally, this approach gives the unfortunate impression that you
>   apparently can't afford to provide legitimate support for your
>   offerings, an impression that I'm sure you don't want to convey.
>
> More information about this specific issue can be found at
>   [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745) and
>   [Reach out to Apigee about outsourcing their support to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261678/102937).
>
> Thank you for listening.
>
> Robert Harvey
>   Stack Overflow Moderator

I found especially amusing the fact that, when I tried to send this from their "Send Feedback" page, the button labelled "Submit Feedback" didn't work. :)

Comment: help@apigee.com perhaps? :)  Or usually more effective, sales@apigee.com ...

Comment: I could try.  That one is not listed on their website.  They *really* want people that are not on a support contract to go to Stack Overflow for support.

Comment: "*I found especially amusing the fact that, when I tried to send this from their "Send Feedback" page, the button labelled "Submit Feedback" didn't work.*" — have you considered [asking a question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=apigee)..?

Comment: “they” should be “users” in the phrase “that give the impression that they can obtain support for company products at Stack Overflow”.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Both of those are listed on the help page, actually, that's where I got them from.

Comment: @Joe: Still can't see it.  I sent it to that address anyway; we'll see what happens.

Comment: SpringSource (now Pivotal Software) just started doing this as well.  I'm not sure the SO founders had in mind becoming everybody's support site.

Comment: @JimGarrison link?

Comment: @DanielA.White http://spring.io/blog/2014/06/18/retiring-the-forum-spring-io-website

Comment: @JimGarrison: At least there's some explanation about what is going on there.  Based on the comments below that post, their user community is keenly aware of the tradeoffs.

Comment: Apigee responded.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Interestingly, that post contains these spellings: "stackoverflow.com", "StackOverflow", and "StackOverflow.com".

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please check with Socrata too. Even the tag wiki on SO is being used like an advertisement to [indicate that work has been _officially outsourced_ to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/socrata/info). I have already raised a mod flag for that tag wiki a few days ago

Comment: @Payeli i would post a new question.