# Why is it possible to prespecify tags to Ask a Question?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

There's a spate of meta discussions concerning companies that direct support questions here without really describing the appropriate scope (the best attempts say "technical", which could equally describe SuperUser questions).

Many of them provide a link to the "Ask a Question" page with a project-associated (or worse, company-generic) tag prefilled.  [Allegedly that bypasses the "How to Ask a Question" guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261702/103167).

In that case, why does "Ask a Question" accept a list of prespecified tags?  Why are direct links from off-site to "Ask a Question" allowed at all?

I suggest that only meta discussions and the Ask a Question button itself should be allowed to direct-link to the "Ask a Question" page, all other such links should get intercepted and sent to the FAQ.

Comment: Or just make sure that the help center popup is shown (if the user hasn't seen it already) even if using this method to navigate to the ask a question page.  Trying to change the behavior of the page based on the referrer seems like a bad idea.

Comment: To be fair, I think new users must still login and be presented with an abbreviated version of the "how to ask" page, but that's a tiny fraction of the material available in the Help Center, and it's not going to help people arriving under false pretenses (attempting to get Customer Support).

Comment: @Robert: When did SO start requiring new users to login?

Comment: When we began getting flooded with low-quality questions (it's been awhile).  You don't have to log in to post an answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: perhaps we could include some kind of "we are not customer support" disclaimer as part of the account setup process?  (Or do we already?)  Perhaps when the user arrives via a link with tags prepopulated we could even be more specific, "We are not customer support for company X"?

Comment: Given that direct links to Ask a Question are allowed, why shouldn't it allow pre-specified tags? This should help ensure that the correct tags are used.

Comment: Someone with the powers should maybe go through logs and look what this feature is used for

Comment: @Barmar: Entering the right tag is an incredibly small part of writing a good question.  If the user can't follow instructions on the referring site concerning a tag, their question is bound for `/dev/nul` anyway.