# It's not [intuit]ive

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, outsourcing

So we have [intuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit) and [intuit-partner-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit-partner-platform). The latter was [recommended by Intuit on their site](https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2012/12/04/ipp-forum-topics-moving-to-stackoverflow) in Dec of 2012 (it's actually why I joined SO)

> Our team is
>   committed to participation on StackOverflow and **will continue to field
>   questions there for anything tagged "Intuit Partner Platform"**.  We
>   encourage our broader community of IPP developers to share their wealth
>   of knowledge as well. By doing this we hope to foster a strong IPP
>   community with a wealth of information easily available and easily
>   searchable on StackOverflow.

There [was](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261538/reach-out-to-intuit-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow) a support presence on the longer tag, but Intuit has a new forum for developers and no longer mentions SO sadly. I think [intuit-partner-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit-partner-platform) should be preserved for the handful of pages still floating around recommending it. It does have 61 followers and appears to be actively answered by some solid people.

[intuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit) is just plain confusing. It's not useful and the excerpt (no wiki) talks about the company, not the software (we have appropriate tags for all of their software)

> Intuit is a software company based in Mountain View, California. It is the developer of Tax products for consumers and professionals (TurboTax, ProTax) as well as Small Business and Personal Finance management solutions (QuickBooks, Mint).

The largest strike against it, however, is its overlap with [intuit-partner-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit-partner-platform). Of the 258 questions, 149 are also tagged [intuit-partner-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intuit-partner-platform). I would say the remainder could be retagged IPP without issue.

Comment: inb4 burnination request for all three [tag:intuit] [tag:partner] [tag:platform]

Comment: Thanks for posting this request and allowing the community to weigh in! For passers-by: please note that burninating a tag is the process of carefully moderating a specific piece of Stack Overflow (please think twice before doing tag-only mass edits, as they can be counter-productive); once the community reaches a consensus, burnination can proceed. For more info, see [What is the process for burninating tags?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).

Comment: *It does have 61 followers and appears to be actively answered by some solid people.* We wouldn't burninate a tag for not getting new questions, would we? This is kind of a tangent, but as long as there's useful content that's properly using a tag, the tag should stick around, right?

Comment: @BSMP Burnination is only for [tags that meet certain criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). Not having questions asked frequently is not a criteria used for this. Generally it's for removing vague or confusing tags

Comment: @BSMP  The 61 followers are for intuit-partner-platform with 804 question, inuit has only 14 followers and 255 questions (149 of those also have both)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I wasn't confused on which tag had how many followers, just wondering what the OP's defense of the intuit-partner-platform tag meant for how tags are chosen for burnination.

Comment: Either way, having two tags for the same thing isn't very useful.

Comment: alternative pun: Cleanup? I'm [intuit]!

Comment: Having a tag the name of a company is pretty useless on the whole (unless it is a single- or major-product company where the company and product are fully interchangeable, like [twitter]). How much use would a [microsoft] tag be (except for trolls...)?

Comment: Why not just make [intuit] a synonym?