# New Tag Request - buddy.com

Tags: discussion, tags, outsourcing

Buddy Platform is a new mobile BaaS provider featuring a JS/iOS/.NET SDK with a REST API exposed at [api.buddyplatform.com](https://api.buddyplatform.com)

Stack Overflow is being used to discuss Buddy Platform here:

- [Create (upload) picture on Buddy platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391477/create-upload-picture-on-buddy-platform)

Disclosure: I am a Buddy employee, having the tag will help us internally to respond to Q&A using Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might be checking with Tim Post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261202/578411

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/product-support-redirects-to-stack-overflow/195562#195562

Comment: That's not a particularly good question. Not something I'd create a tag for.

Comment: This seems like a fairly organic use of StackOverflow to ask technical questions about our SDK. Buddy doesn't explicitly use SO as a customer support tool but we'd like to support customers coming here to ask defined questions rather than outsourcing support to the SO community. We have GitHub issues for tracking feature requests, etc.

Comment: So give it some time until there are some quality questions on the topic and then a tag can be created.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We get a lot of requests from project teams about how they can use Stack Overflow to support their communities. Stack Overflow works really well for technical support, as long as you're not trying to outsource your entire customer support channel to Stack Exchange. There's a good meta post covering the issue below; the top two answers are worth reading:

[Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/98786)

In that post, it is suggested that support has to come from the community first. The idea that there should be a tag created just yet is a bit inside-out — hence I believe why you are seeing the down-votes here.

I don't suggest any  ill intentions in your part. I actually think you are going about this in this in the right way. I would only suggest that you gather up a few more ***quality*** examples of how you would like to use Stack Overflow for support, and then 'flag' those questions for moderator attention if the tag seems fit. That way the support for your product grows organically rather than the appearance of something that seems just a little bit spammy.

Apologies if we got off on the wrong foot. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Robert. I think everyone here was a little excited that developers were discussing the product on SO and wanted to do what we could to encourage discussion. We'll continue to keep an eye on people using the community for technical guidance.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like someone added the tag. I'll give you some advice for moving forward:

#### Get active on the site, asap :)

The buddy developers helping folks on Stack Overflow are going to need enough reputation to actually help your users. This means that they're going to need to be able to edit posts without the need for edit approval, re-tag questions, and (perhaps most importantly) cast votes to close or re-open.

Our community is *entirely* self-moderated, so in order to ensure that your customers have the best possible experience on our site, *you need to be a part of that community that's doing the moderation*.

What languages and technologies did you use to build buddy? I'm sure you could find lots of questions about those, but not necessiarly related to buddy that could use some great answers. Someone there is going to need about 5k rep.

#### Monitor the tag religiously

You don't have to worry much about looking after folks that have some experience with the site asking questions here, they know the ropes. However, as we've found, quite a few third-party referrals to Stack Overflow end up becoming new users. [Keep an eye out for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buddy.com) at a minimum, I highly recommend hovering over the tag and clicking on the 'subscribe' link so you get a handy email digest of new questions. You can even pipe that through your support infrastructure if you wish.

#### Psst, hey mister, would you like to buy a Rolex?

Avoid being construed as spammy, which isn't terribly hard to do. When you edit your tag wiki, remember that it's not a showcase, but a utility that saves you time. Anything you repeatedly tell developers in the course of helping them should probably find a heading on the tag wiki (info) page - and that can become your 'Swiss Army' link of sorts. It's also a great place to toss a mini-tutorial for folks getting started.

We'll have additional guidance in our help center shortly, but this is the gist of it that now applies for you. Good luck, welcome to the site - now get crackin'!