# LinkedIn directing people to SO?

Tags: discussion

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/stacking-api-support-linkedin

Is this really happening?

Can we no longer provide comments to the effect of "Take this up with the support team for XYZ Product."

How is this going to be handled within the SO community? How long before other companies claim to have their "engineers" monitoring SO?

Quote:

> Justin Kominar, Nov 24, 2014
>
> We have a pretty important saying around here at LinkedIn, and it's that members come first. Whether you're building your professional identity on linkedin.com or developing professional integrations with our API, you're a 'member' of our community. In an effort to bring our developer-centric member support to the next level, we are happy to announce that starting today, November 24th, we will begin actively contributing our platform-specific expertise to the talented community of developers that live at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin).
>
> In concert with this announcement, we would also like to inform you that we have decided to retire the current [forums](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum) on the [developer.linkedin.com](http://developer.linkedin.com) website. We recognize that there is lots of useful content within the forums. To help out during the transition period, they will remain available for reference to the public in a read-only state.
>
> Going forward, if you have questions about the LinkedIn API, the best place to ask them will be at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin). The sheer brain-power of the Stack community, combined with the domain-specific knowledge that LinkedIn's engineers bring to the table will get you the highest quality answers in the shortest amount of time.
>
> Before asking your LinkedIn API-related questions at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin), please make sure you:
>
> - Tagged your question with the **#linkedin** hashtag, or the LinkedIn engineers likely won't see them!
> - Read through StackOverflow's [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, to make sure your question doesn't get down-voted.
> - Remember that StackOverflow is for technical "How-To" kinds of questions and answers. If you have general questions about LinkedIn, please continue to use https://help.linkedin.com for support.
>
> Finally, if you still have an open issues previously reported on the LinkedIn forums, please re-submit on StackOverflow for continued support. We look forward to providing continued guidance to the developer community in this new environment!

Comment: [It happens](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277810/ie-web-development-support-moving-to-stack-overflow)

Comment: That seems like a reasonable post, they're linking to everything they should and calling out specifically that it's only for technical questions... Not sure about the "how-to", but it's considerably better than others I've seen.

Comment: @Ben It will be interesting to see if the support team sticks to the rules and doesn't merely become [Help Vampires](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/2191572)

Comment: The only thing that worries me is `if you still have an open issues previously reported on the LinkedIn forums` almost read like "if you previously reported a bug...."

Comment: I wonder if SO needs to start some sort of Company XYZ official support verification account statuses so that we can differentiate whether or not those companies are actually helping or hurting the community.

Comment: Tim Post normally handles this kind of stuff: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/578411 and another case: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261199/reach-out-to-e107-about-outsourcing-their-support-to-stack-overflow/261202#261202 but I think he is still on leave ...

Comment: The [linkedin unanswered question percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/linkedin/topusers) is pretty abysmal, so hopefully they can commit some more resources to answering questions soon. Also, "Tagged your question with the #linkedin hashtag..." is really bugging me.

Comment: New feature request: auto-strip the hash character from the front of any new tag. Actually, is it even a legal character for a tag here?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Excellent link for the unanswered percentages. I wanted to rip my eyes out while reading that hastag line.

Comment: From the FAQ: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: I'm a little concerned with this one after looking at a couple of questions on that tag... [Am I wrong, or is question inappropriate for SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362115/linkedin-api-key-just-dissapeared)

Comment: FWIW, it looks like this user is one of LinkedIn's folks attempting to answer questions on that tag: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4009562/justin-kominar

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Pretty much it right there, considering I've seen that one and another that was blatently a "Your site isn't working for me, LinkedIn." question. (I flagged the second one as I knew for sure that doesn't belong here, I'm unsure on the one I linked and what I would flag as...)

Comment: @Kendra I deleted my initial comment because I thought it was off-topic but I'm glad you agree. My original comment: [The Executive Team](http://previews.123rf.com/images/yayayoy/yayayoy1107/yayayoy110700005/9920725-happy-boss-smoking-cigar-with-legs-over-table-boss-cartoon-man.jpg)

Comment: Considering that out of all the questions asked since yesterday, there's only a single upvote between them (and all others have a score of 0 or less), I can't say they're off to a rousing start.

Comment: http://linkedin.stackexchange.com anyone? If they want to "offshore" things then I see no reason SO shouldn't within it's own network. I wonder if these companies realize that they are basically sending their clients to the wolves especially when their question is sub-par. I wonder if SO will be sued lol

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that wouldn't stop the influx of questions in SO about it. Migrating the questions would be a hassle.

Comment: @Compass True. I would just hope that SO is going to eventually allow companies to buy sub-domains in which only their qualified employees can register and answer questions. Then LinkedIn and Microsoft can tell people to go there and not plaster sub-par questions on SO. This will probably be a subscription service but still cheaper than hosting and maintaining their own forums.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus There was previously an option for companies to pay for private hosted StackExchange instances. It apparently didn't work out, and is no longer offered. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/

Comment: @AndrewMedico thank you, any chance there was a Meta about this? I've only found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones

Comment: Yes, several: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/stack-exchange-for-in-house-us http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70970/can-you-host-the-stackexchange-software-yourself-to-create-a-site

Comment: @AndrewMedico Ah thank you. I think this statement `I know Stack Exchange is not interested in setting up public forums specifically for companies to support their own products.` from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions answers my question the best though because I wasn't suggesting that companies do the hosting themselves.

Comment: So I guess I am just circling around the idea of these companies proposing stuff on http://area51.stackexchange.com/ and trying their hardest to make their SE sub-domain a reality just like SharePoint and SalesForce

Comment: Another post requesting that the community team reach out to LinkedIn has been written [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281019/3005188).

Comment: @Ffisegydd Thanks for getting that up. It will be interesting to see what LinkedIn does.