# Reach out to LinkedIn about outsourcing their developer support to Stack Overflow

Tags: support, outsourcing

LinkedIn recently [closed their support and began directing their users to use Stack Overflow](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/stacking-api-support-linkedin). This has seen an upsurge in questions within [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin). This has been previously brought up on Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278748/linkedin-directing-people-to-so) where it was closed as a duplicate.

Unfortunately, the majority of these questions are off topic or just generally not up to the standard expected. At the time of writing, 20 out of the last 30 questions in the tag have been closed.

In defense of LinkedIn, they do link to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in their announcement, but this hasn't stopped multiple users from complaining when their question is closed and replying with something along the lines of "But LinkedIn told us to come here!".

**Is it possible for someone from the community team to reach out to LinkedIn and try to come to some kind of arrangement?**

As it stands we're closing a significant number of questions, this is frustrating for us, it [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27597526/get-full-profile-using-linkedin-apis-issues#comment43657991_27597526) [frustrating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559981/how-do-apps-like-weave-show-mutual-linkedin-connections-1st-degree-between-two#comment43550449_27559981) for the users, and it is probably frustrating the LinkedIn devs.

Comment: The tag is also [lacking sufficiently experienced users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/linkedin/topusers) to handle the load. There appears to be just [one LinkedIn developer active here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4009562/justin-kominar), who simply doesn't have the reputation to do much in the way of closing and editing.

Comment: Two more LinkedIn employees that are far less active: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1718199/kamyar-mohager and http://stackoverflow.com/users/751095/adam-trachtenberg; Adam hasn't posted since April. Both also lack Stack Overflow experience.

Comment: The active developer has only cast 1 vote till date. Not helpful.

Comment: Isn't it kind of rude to just cancel your support site and throw it onto Stack Overflow?

Comment: @JoeSwindell - I told my family I'm not answering any more parenting questions, and to go to http://parenting.stackexchange.com for help instead.  Results have been mixed to negative.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables BINGO

Comment: @JoeSwindell it is not necessarily bad on its own. after all Microsoft did the same thing just last month, see here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277811/3915817 it is more a question of how a site handles the transition. In this case though it seems like they handled it poorly.

Comment: Is it worth editing the title from "support" to "developer support"? When I first read it I thought that LI was on the downward spiral and telling all their users to go to SO with questions -- not just the devs.

Comment: That is a good call. I copied the title style from other "reach out" questions but I'll edit and add that in now.

Comment: If people can't even read the whole announcement, how can they be expected to read the "How to ask" page?

Comment: "Tagged your question with the #linkedin hashtag" - Well there's your problem. They think this is Twitter.

Comment: I would add to this renaming the tag from "linkedin" to "linkedin-api" which is what people are supposed to ask here. (cc @BradLarson)

Comment: Are api questions off topic for stackoverflow? it seems some of these questions are being closed simply because someone's asking about how to use a specific api endpoint. I figured at least the api questions that showed attempts/research would be relevant, but no, those are getting closed too.

Comment: @KevinB that begs for examples.

Comment: @KevinB: the questions that are being closed are not about programming against the API, but about what data the API can provide, or the API not providing certain functionality, or any number of such questions that *only LinkedIn support can answer*.

Comment: Let's get free support from StackOverflow they said. Nothing can go wrong they said (;

Comment: @KevinB the API questions that I've seen (also anecdotal) tend to be "can someone give-me-code/tell-me-how to do X action with the linkedin-api" and not "I need help with the code I've written," which makes those questions a poor fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Area51 shows that it can take a good deal of time before a stable community builds around a specific topic in a way that's compatible with the SE model.  Linkedin didn't have that time yet.

Comment: I suggest that the `[linkedin]` tag (and any related, such as `[linked-in]`, etc) should be burninated, and changes should be made to prevent these tags from being recreated. Perhaps there should be an Area 51 request to create linkedin.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm not sure burnination is a proper solution. (1) There are some good questions concerning linkedin that are asked, burninating would remove the appropriate tag from these genuine questions. (2) If LinkedIn are still linking people to ask questions here, then their users will still ask questions, they'll just use some other tags that are either random or tangentially related. This would mean the same poor content is being asked, it would just be much more difficult to find.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - sounds like a great idea! Would this also get me out of the interminable "drive-kids-to-place-X/drive-kids-to-place-Y/drive-parent-out-of-mind" stuff? :-)

Comment: What sort of "arrangement" are you suggesting is necessary? I don't see why Stack Overflow should need to especially worry about this, as the real losers here are LinkedIn. If LinkedIn want to ask their shitty questions here to get closed and deleted, that's their problem.

Comment: I don't know what the arrangement would be. Speak to LI and explain the issue I suppose, and see what conversation can be had. There are various previous meta questions for different websites/services where the same thing has occurred (see the Related list to the right). Also, everyone loses if this continues: we have to spend time and effort closing poor quality questions, LI users have nowhere to go for help, and LI gain a bad rep with their dev users.

Comment: @Ffisegydd "LI gain[s] a bad rep" That's pretty much what LI should be concerned about. In my book they went from being "meh" to being like the neighbor who is not breaking the the letter of the rules (LI users posting here are ignoring SO rules; LI *itself* is not) but is still a significant nuisance in the neighborhood. Is this the kind of individual I want to associate with? Nope.

Comment: This is a very bad tendency. Projects keep sending their users to here because  they think the community will do what they are supposed to!

Comment: Just a reminder that we *do* have a [Can I support my product on this site?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) FAQ page, maybe LinkedIn should've read that ;)

Comment: @KHeaney: The big difference between the Microsoft case and most of these other project "moving developer support to SO" announcements is that Microsoft already had separate corporate and community support systems, so moving community support into the SO ecosystem didn't bring a bunch of unlock-my-account requests with it.

Comment: The questions I've seen and CV'd lately resemble bug reports and feature requests more so than genuine questions about how to use the API. It is one thing to outsource specific questions about API usage and other to use StackOverflow as an issue tracker system.

Comment: I think you've made a major misread there. They have neither moved not outsourced their support to Stack Overflow. They've simply **closed** their support, in the same time informing, the programming questions about API may be asked and answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: At this point, I sort of wonder whether there's any team left over there at all: nothing on developer.linkedin.com seems to have been updated in a year or more, and there doesn't seem much evidence anyone is helping out on SO. Pity that there's no way to reflect that on this side.

Answer (score 37):

It is possible for companies to offer API support via Stack Overflow and have it work well for every party involved, but this isn't that. At least not yet.

The Community Team (of which I'm a member) is getting in touch with folks at LinkedIn. We're very close to a [particularly large holiday](https://isitchristmas.com/) in the U.S. so it may take a little time, but we're sorting this. Hold tight!

---

**Update**

*A few days ago, [LinkedIn announced they’re significantly limiting the capabilities of their public API](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes). The change has caused an uptick in questions using the [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) tag, beyond what the community was already struggling to keep up with.*

*The silver lining is that with decreased capabilities, the number of questions about the LinkedIn API should wane over time. In the immediate term, we’ve provided the LinkedIn team with recommendations for mitigating the issues caused by these changes; I'm hoping they’ll contribute some time to making the transition easier.*

Answer (score -13):

> LinkedIn recently closed their support and began directing their users to use Stack Overflow. This has seen an upsurge in questions within [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin)...
>
> Is it possible for someone from the community team to reach out to LinkedIn and try to come to some kind of arrangement?

Since Linkedin appears to be interested in Stack Exchange's model of support...

One potential solution is to actually outsource Linkedin support to the Stack Exchange network. Scope it as exists for Stack Overflow, Super User, etc. That is, the community will make a good faith effort to answer helpful or useful questions, and it will try to point users to existing questions and answers if they exist. Agree on pricing an terms, and then set up a Linkedin Stack Exchange.

Another solution is send in the consultants: for a fee, Stack Exchange sets up a site for Linkedin, and then Stack Exchange walks away. Its up to Linkedin to manage the site.

Comment: they tried something like this with [facebook.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook.stackoverflow/info). Didn't end up well, "subsite has been removed (with much rejoicing)"

Comment: Oh, I did not know that experiment was already run. Do you think it had to do with the particular instance of the problem (Facebook and its non-technical users)? Or is it a more generalized issue (will it affect technical users too; users will reject a Stack Exchange based help system)? Or is Stack Exchange software the wrong tool for the job (it has no business trying to be a support tool (this one seems distant to me since its seems like a good self-help tool And the community-based means sites can carry fewer support personnel).

Comment: per my recollection it had more to do with insufficient participation of FB team in answering questions. Though you better simply check posts in that MSE tag for more accurate details