# What are the number one tags for low quality posts?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, question-quality

I've been frequenting [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tagged questions while occasionally drifting to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) tags. I see an overwhelming amount of low quality questions within jQuery especially, but I'm wondering if is only because I have spent the most time in that area.

It seems to me there are a great number of 1 rep askers who cannot be bothered to spend more than 0.3 seconds on their question, leaving the community dealing with a great amount of little messes to clean up.

So I began wondering, since the Stack Overflow system can flag low quality posts automagically, which tags regularly have the largest percentage of total questions flagged as low quality?

Comment: SO is marketed as a site for "professional and enthusiast programmers".  You listed tags that are a fairly overwhelmed with enthusiasm.  Use the Preferences tab in your profile if you are not enthusiastic about them.

Comment: Flags aren't in SEDE but downvoter might tell you something: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/269767/what-are-the-number-one-tags-for-low-quality-posts

Comment: It's difficult to imagine anything other than a low quaity question with jQuery.

Comment: The more popular the technology is, more attraction to develop with it, more new users try and fail, and thus, more low quality posts they made.

Comment: I think the problem is as Andrew T. says: the lower the barrier to entry (php and javascript having very low barriers to entry) the more noise you will get in the dedication of those asking questions about it. The problem with this is that you'd have to look at tag combinations I think, simply since by examining single tags in isolation, you risk "throwing the baby out with the bathwater". You could try to correlate tag combinations (or lack of additional tags to a problematic tag) with downvotes?

Comment: To be fair, I just checked jquery and found only one 'member for today' 1-point troll/vampire on the first page.

Comment: The C tag has seven:(

Comment: @MartinJames Python and Java have tons. I won't even start to count, but I've downvoted ~15 today already and am only browsing SO during compiling and other downtime...

Comment: tag: VBA - 4,188 of my downvotes in just 2 years.

Comment: I have to agree with @vba4all.  VBA seems to be overrun with **nonprogrammers** asking "give me teh codez?"

Comment: @rene downvotes per post in a tag might be more informational

Comment: [tag:sql] is probably one of the top for low-quality questions.

Comment: Consider this: the larger the tag audience is, the more eyes are on a given question and therefore more flags/votes are cast. Yet the threshold for closing a question is 5 and does not scale with the tag popularity. (Some really low quality questions in obscure tags are hard to close as a consequence)

Comment: @rene now we need to take that page, and divide by http://stackoverflow.com/tags page, and look at quality density.

Comment: @Degustaf Well, of course it is... VBA is intended to be used by nonprogrammers.

Comment: @Yakk feel free to fork my query, I'm not emotional attached to it....

Comment: @rene I've mostly suppressed by SQL knowledge.  You are going to make me unearth it...

Comment: hi can u help my regex dont work ^(?!=[\'.-(]*).*[<>]?[<>]?$\n

Comment: **[LinkedIn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281019/reach-out-to-linkedin-about-outsourcing-their-developer-support-to-stack-overflo)** is probably a good candidate as far as percentage is concerned.

Comment: @Yakk http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/270223/353060/what-are-the-number-one-tags-for-low-quality-posts - php pretty bad. generic tags like if-statement bad. jquery / javascript / vba do OK on this metric

Comment: @JRichardSnape heh, I wonder what the predictive power of tags would be towards "this post is going to be locked"?  And wow, ruby-on-rails looks like paradise.