# Is it reasonable to explicitly say what's off-topic in a tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

The [linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linkedin) tag is still receiving plenty of junk questions ([background](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281019/reach-out-to-linkedin-about-outsourcing-their-developer-support-to-stack-overflo)), with a lot of users stating they were sent here by LinkedIn (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469991/linkedin-people-search-api-and-updated-developer-program)).

I thought it might be useful to add some material to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linkedin/info) to explicitly warn people off:

> [original text describing the tag]
>
> Please ensure that your [question is not off-topic for
> StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company/255746#255746) before asking it here. [Even if LinkedIn directed
> you here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281019/reach-out-to-linkedin-about-outsourcing-their-developer-support-to-stack-overflo), the rules for what can be asked here are determined by
> StackOverflow, not LinkedIn.
>
> In particular, questions about LinkedIn's terms of service, with
> registering for a service with them, or what APIs they will be
> offering in the future, are all off-topic for StackOverflow.
>
> You may be able to contact LinkedIn customer support via [this
> link](https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/a/b).

I later noticed that this doesn't seem to have happened with some other tags that have been the target of similar outsourcing (I checked [ops-hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ops-hub), [soundcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/soundcloud), [travis-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci)), so I thought I'd better make sure it's ok. Also the [tag wiki guide](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) doesn't say anything about doing something like this.

Is this kind of change to the tag wiki acceptable/reasonable?

Anyone think it'll actually have any effect? :-)

Comment: It's reasonable, but no one who would be affected by it is ever going to read it there.