# Is Stack Overflow becoming a support forums platform?

Tags: discussion

Reading recent blog post, it looks like moving support forums to Stack Overflow is encouraged:

[Why Sencha is moving its support forums to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/30/why-sencha-is-moving-its-support-forums-to-stack-overflow/)

On the surface, that would be fine for questions and answers that are on topic for Stack Overflow. But, the phrase support forum is something different from Stack Overflow. While there is certain overlap, it is not an interchangeable term. And a plain invitation on an official blog post, saying nothing about quality and topicality requirements is an invitation for all kind of off topic and poor questions.

Also, mentioning a highly off topic and inappropriate [curl question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55884514/what-is-the-incentive-for-curl-to-release-the-library-for-free) in the blog post opens another can of worms.

Is Stack Overflow changing directions to Support Overflow, Homework Overflow, etc. or is original goal of being highly focused quality Q/A site still standing?

Comment: Looking forward to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/3001761 getting quietly deleted...

Comment: _“We have an MVP program, and so we’re going to put a contest in place in those first 30 days for the most answers,” says Blumenthal. “There’s a number of prizes that we’ll publicly announce, mostly differing levels of Amazon gift cards and swag. You guys have those leaderboards so makes it pretty easy.”_

So now they’re adding incentives to post answers other than rep, or _helping_ users. This is a _Quantity over Quality_ approach, and as such it’s not a fit with SO’s mission of Quality Q&A.

Comment: Related: [Reach out to LinkedIn about outsourcing their developer support to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281019) and [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374)

Comment: Isn't this a win for both companies? SE gets a bigger audience for SO Teams ads etc., Sencha doesn't need to use their own people to support customers and the community has to deal with the backlash, but that's no problem either when the whole Monica situation has settled and they can go back to ignore meta, because it is so toxic.

Comment: @Tom Not really. Not all support questions are suitable for Stack Overflow. And "replacing" support forums with SO will inevitably bring those here. Encouraging developers working on some product to share their knowledge here is one thing (good one) but bringing each and every support question is something completely different.

Comment: Additional incentives for posting answers is going to make it fun trying to close the inevitable flow of off-topic questions. Maybe if we could somehow restrict support questions to just one tag and then everyone could go ahead and ignore that tag? So if something is tagged `sencha` then other tags are dropped?

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC The misunderstanding here is that a win for SE is not a win for the community. The knowledge database already exists with a solid foundation, so in order to keep growing SE needs to get more users in, for example by widening the scope. This already happened in the past, for example by removing 'close vote' reasons, supporting other companies to move their support traffic to SO is just another step. And yes, we as the community aren't so happy about it, but we can be ignored and we aren't in the majority either. There will always be someone eager enough to answer anything.

Comment: Reading the blog post: "*of that, Stack Overflow is a better way to surface questions and answers than bulletin board software.*" this is a true statement. Bulletin board systems aren't that great to search in. "*We’ve got robust search*" also a true statement. The search doesn't break and will give you the correct output for correct input. "*and a pretty strong presence in search results*" hey, 3 for 3 in true statements. SO is doing well in the SEO department. What the three true statement don't quite describe is that the search within SO is not great at bringing you the results.

Comment: The "becoming" can probably be removed from the question title.

Comment: I will honestly laugh when the employees of Sencha can't post comments for clarification due to a lack of reputation as they are new SO users (especially if they post an answer asking for clarification and get it deleted).

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean Stack Overflow in the broader sense (like across Stack Exchange) or in the scope of the Stack Overflow site, and whether you think that article asserts it to mean the SO site?  Having said that, Stack Overflow Teams (Integration and Enterprise) aren't new concepts.  So, I wouldn't characterize this as an indication of changing direction - since a degree of product\organization support platform offerings has existed for awhile.  It seems more like a scope and accessibility as well as impact and discovery concern rather then vision.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be the direction of the company. [The original vision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297863/155739) has been [lost](https://kera.name/articles/2019/10/mistake-overflow-one-companys-catalogue-of-errors/).

Comment: Voting up because it's true / Shedding a tear whlie I do :-(

Comment: no offense, but it's audacious of you to cite your own 2017 answer (which was not the accepted answer of that question) as the original vision of the company.  I find your 2014 answer much [more acceptable and original](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/1366179).  With special mention to the wiki answer [The Goal of Stack Overflow, According to All the Related Things!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254773/1366179)

Answer (score 24):

I'm gonna start worrying about this in earnest when we have ***employees*** telling us that we can't close poor Sencha questions because of Reasons™, whereas any other question which is just as poor won't even get the same time of day.

Comment: Since this blog post mentions blatantly off topic culr question as great example, I am already worried.

Comment: SE employees have the tendency to avoid telling us anything about what SE thinks the future of the site would be until it's post-factum. There have been growing concerned about where that future lies and it's normal to be at least a little bit anxious. The continued silence from SE on the future of the site just amplifies these doubts and the (expected) silence on this matter would bring even more worry. Until SE actually *talk to us*, I believe at least a small dose of unease is justified.

Comment: Prediction: it's going to happen.  Sencha outsources their support, their customers ask poor questions, they get closed, they complain to Sencha, Sencha complains to SE, they get reopened, and closers get scolded.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC:  [We don't talk about](https://medium.com/@makotothedragon/dear-stack-overflow-i-really-want-to-talk-but-i-dont-believe-you-ll-listen-to-me-anymore-9b17cc9c05f6) [that damn curl answer here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1079354)

Comment: @VLAZ:  We're beyond talk, honestly.  My stance is simple - if an employee comes in and tells us how we're meant to moderate this content, then and *only* then should we panic.

Comment: @fbueckert:  I fail to see how this is any different from the myriad of projects that try to do this with less fanfare or endorsement from Up Above.  It's only when that particular angle *changes* does it make sense to get up in arms about it.  Frankly...if paid customers are asking for support on a site like *this*, something has already happened already that we can't repair.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the angle that changing, @Makoto.  It's gonna look awful bad if SO is accepting Sencha support, only to have their users get bad experiences because the expectation mismatch is so great.  The only thing I think that could fix that would be for SE to make our expectations far clearer to new users.  Anything else is just asking curators to try to redirect one more stream of sewage.

Comment: Correct. Keep doing what you're doing and making the site what you want it to be until you are told/forced to stop. That is my approach. We will sometimes disagree on the details, but as long as we're all in agreement on the big picture, we can still continue to maintain this site as the best programming resource on the web.

Comment: @fbueckert: I get that there's been a lot of high volatility activity on the network in the last month or two - but I'm not gonna leech onto every announcement as some kind of conspiracy against the original mission.  Being "beyond talk" also means that the company could also be beyond talking about it, since they announced this decision unilaterally in a very, very high visibility way.  I don't disagree that there's a lot of discomfort around this issue, but I'm not seeing a lot of benefit to panicking about it.  Besides...if the company wants to ruin the platform, it's their call.

Comment: I admit that there's probably some pessimism in my assessment.  I don't think it amounts to panic, but a depressing assessment of the state of SE.  I'm of the same opinion as Cody; maintain standards.  If SE decides to override the community, well, they know what side their bread is buttered on.

Comment: @Makoto Actually, after the curl incident it became blatantly obvious in which direction SO is going... it will not end up well... I don't give up easily and that is why I am still here, but I no longer expect that anything will change for the better.

Comment: I really feel like some of you folks are reading too much into "the curl incident".

Comment: @CodyGray:  To be honest every time I see it brought up in blog posts or official statements, much like the one I read in the blog post today, the scar where I felt like I was completely stabbed in the back on this starts to ache.  Now that may be reading into it a bit much or may be a bit too dramatic.  But that scar still runs deep, and I had done a decent job of forgetting about it until today.

Answer (score -10):

The answer depends on if you equate a support forum with a discussion forum, or more a help ticket/request.

I view it more as the latter, and that does run counter to the stated intent of SO (and any other SE site), according to the [Tour Page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (emphasis added

> Ask questions, get answers, no distractions
>
> This site is all about getting answers. **It's not a discussion forum.** There's no chit-chat.
>
> Just questions...
>
> ... and answers

Using SO as a community-based tech support *FAQ* would seem to be a more appropriate fit. I think the base service itself could be used as a community forum, but I think it'd have to be operated completely separated from SO/SE or else you do run the risk of off topic questions leaking into other communities. In other words, offer it as SaaS similar to Stack Overflow for Teams/Enterprise, but publicly available.

I'm a very cynical person and now speaking more broadly than just SO, but also for other cloud and social media outlets. I view a company moving to a community-based cloud service for their official "support forum" as a cost savings move to offload most if not all their support to the community.

I use several SaaS services push people to SO or advertise that they monitor XYZ. But then I see questions that only the company can really answer go unanswered forever. Or aren't technical questions, but more something that their sales team should respond. I might eventually see a "hard" question answered by someone tagged as an employee, but then they skip over multiple easy ones that would have been quick to assist with.

Comment: SO is neither a support forum, nor a help desk system.  It's a continual perception it is, but that perception runs headlong into curators, and generally leaves everybody the worse for wear.