# The LinkedIn Partner Program is sending customer support questions to SO

Tags: discussion

It looks like the LinkedIn Partner Program is re-directing their customer support questions to Stack Overflow. While they have previously [directed API questions to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278748/linkedin-directing-people-to-so) it looks like they are also re-directing any question even if it is not a fit for Stack Overflow. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363328/not-able-to-apply-to-linkedin-partner-program):

> I've already had a conversation with LinkedIn support stating they're unable to help and I should ask here.

Is there anything that can be done to prevent LinkedIn from directing these questions here that just end up getting closed?

- *[Issues in Partner Program Application Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50296690/issues-in-partner-program-application-form)*
- *[LinkedIn Support: Broken Link in partner program application platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526951/linkedin-support-broken-link-in-partner-program-application-platform)*
- *[LinkedIn Partner Program for User's Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574285/linkedin-partner-program-for-users-connections)*
- *[Linkedin Partner Application Non-functional button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591509/linkedin-partner-application-non-functional-button)*
- *[How to access Apply with LinkedIn partnership program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880439/how-to-access-apply-with-linkedin-partnership-program)*

Comment: So there is a difference between "directing people to ask questions" and "people thinking they can ask any question about LinkedIn".  If LinkedIn is doing the former, then that needs fixed.  If the latter is what is happening, then it may still be something LinkedIn can address by changing their help pages, but it is impossible completely fix since it depends on the user.  Obviously the question you quoted suggests they are sending people here, but is that an education for their own people, or documentation?

Comment: Don't worry, Microsoft will buy Stack Overflow next year.

Answer (score 55):

LinkedIn actually does a decent job of warning users on their website:

[image: LinkedIn's interstitial before hitting SO]

So, in this case, it looks like the user either just clicked through without reading or were led here by a LinkedIn support person, who needs to get their hand slapped.

It might be good if one of our Community Managers reached out to LinkedIn. As psubsee2003 mentions [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369060/the-linkedin-partner-program-is-sending-customer-support-questions-to-so/369066?noredirect=1#comment597506_369066), they should be clear that only programming questions regarding their public APIs should be asked.

Comment: I was actually writing a similar answer.  But one thing I think they could be better is they could make it clearer that support questions are not on topic on Stack Overflow.  the phrasing leaves open the interpretation that it is ok to ask a support-type question

Comment: Good point. Added to answer. They could probably just rewrite it to say "only programming questions about our public APIs should be asked" rather than trying to enumerate what should not be asked.

Comment: @aaa90210 I mean, it's always possible someone is struggling with English to begin with and isn't fully aware of what SO is used for. Let's not categorically assume complete stupidity on the part of outsiders.

Comment: Are LinkedIn's API's public? I thought you needed to pay them for access.

Comment: @RobRose their text makes me believe that there are both public and non-public API's