# Being ping-ponged between LinkedIn and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, product-support

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post [Linkedin API access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299752/linkedin-api-access).

I created this post after LinkedIn support told me to, but my question was deleted by the community and I was linked to [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

I created another support ticket with LinkedIn, who closed it again and repeated:

> Thanks for contacting us at LinkedIn! I am Anu and I look forward to
>   making your LinkedIn experience brighter!   In an effort to boost
>   support for our developer community, we moved our online support forum
>   from the Developers site to StackOverflow. The older forums on the
>   Developers site will be available for reference in a read-only state.
>   Before asking LinkedIn API-related questions at StackOverflow, be sure
>   to:
>
> Tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see
>   them.
>
> Read StackOverflow's How to Ask Good Questions guide.
>
> Remember that StackOverflow is for technical questions and answers.
>   For general questions about LinkedIn, please use the LinkedIn Help
>   Center.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I can do?

Comment: Someone should tell LinkedIn that we don’t use #hashtags here

Comment: Very similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369060/ (that question is about the LinkedIn Partner Program, but if that doesn't make a difference, seems like a dupe). LinkedIn's support should not be recommending people to ask non-programming questions on SO

Comment: I can’t promise I’ll have any luck, but I am poking to see if anyone I know that direction can get us to the right place and get the process fixed here so your ticket (and others like it) are properly handled.

Comment: Hi Nick, I appreciate the reply. I understand that in a big company like linkedin it sometimes feels like yelling into the void when you try to raise something like this, but the effort is appreciated! Cheers

Comment: Update from Linkedin:

Hi Paul,

Thanks for your patience! However this is indeed a API query and you would need to rephrase the question and post again so that our developers can look into this.
 
Please post the query once again as your previous query has been removed.
 
Before asking LinkedIn API-related questions at StackOverflow, be sure to:

Tag question with the #linkedin hashtag so LinkedIn engineers will see them.

Read StackOverflow's How to Ask Good Questions guide.

Remember that StackOverflow is for technical questions and answers.

Do try again!

Comment: So to summarise the response from Linkedin: My question (which is about a non-technical aspect of the Linkedin API) is about the Linkedin API, and therefore must be asked on StackOverflow, but they go on to remind me that StackOverflow is only meant to be used for technical questions. Fun times!

Answer (score 24):

I'm truly sorry this happened to you, but unfortunately, this is on LinkedIn, and we can do little to help.

We have extensive guidance on which questions you can ask here, and how companies can support their product here. The ones applicable to this situation are:

- [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746) (I've already shared this one with you when closing the question)
- [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

These kind of support questions are just not acceptable on Stack Overflow, and that's not going to change. Anything that can't be answered by a person knowledgeable in the subject, but not employed at LinkedIn is not a good question here.

Apparently, this is a longstanding issue, and the text you got is very similar to the one quoted in [LinkedIn directing people to SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278748/7296893) (asked in 2014), and there's been [a call to reach out to LinkedIn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281019/7296893) back in 2014 too.

You can try linking them this question and answer, and hope they change their ways. We can also hope a community manager at Stack Overflow picks up on this issue, and has a talk with LinkedIn about our rules. But we can't just reopen your question and hope it gets answered, because that would open the flood gates for other companies to redirect their customer support to Stack Overflow.

If you want to be sure this gets picked up by the community team at Stack Overflow, you can contact them via https://stackoverflow.com/contact, as linked in [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746). Note that this sometimes has a substantial waiting time.

Comment: Hi Erik,

Thanks for the reply, I appreciate the insight and link to previous history on the issue. I've opened another case with Linkedin specifically about their customer service methodology, rather than about my specific issue. Hoping that has a better shot of being reviewed by them, but I won't hold my breath.

Is there a structure I could follow to create an SO question specifically about Linkedin's obvious customer service issues on the "linkedin" tag? They mention linkedin engineers review the tag, so perhaps they would see it?

Cheers

Comment: @PaulSharratt I'm sorry, but that would not be on-topic as well, and will probably get received poorly. These discussions should stay limited to meta. I'd give Nick a chance, he's very high up the food chain at Stack Overflow so might be able to get things done quickly.