# Does Keen IO Link to Stack Overflow Appropriately?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing

I read the [question regarding another company's use of a Stack Overflow link with the heading of "Community"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311368/reach-out-to-orange-and-tell-them-were-not-their-community) and noticed that some of the way [that company](http://orange.biolab.si/) was referencing Stack Overflow was similar to what [Keen IO](https://keen.io/) (A company I currently work for) is doing.  There are some differences in the way we reference Stack Overflow but I'd like to know if this pattern is considered an irritant for any (many?) of us on Stack Overflow.

First, the commonality: Keen IO has a footer labeled "Community" with Stack Overflow as one of the links. It is not the top link, which is unlike Orange but otherwise still links to SO with an associated tag enabled:

[image: Keen IO Community Footer]

Unlike the other company, Keen IO lists SO in a couple of other places with some description that makes it at least a little more clear that SO isn't the primary, or only, "community" resource.

If you click on "Resources" you are directed [here](https://keen.io/community). This page has a section labeled "Stack Overflow" that says:

> STACK OVERFLOW
>
> Check out the keen-io tag. Post questions for technical issues, errors and exceptions. We monitor StackOverflow and will make sure your question gets answered promptly.

Is this a sufficient explanation, or is there something better that should be said here?

Another location with a Stack Overflow link from Keen IO is found on their [support page](https://keen.io/support/). Here it lists it under "Additional Resources" and says:

> Stack Overflow
>
> Implementation questions and troubleshooting are discussed under the keen-io tag.

Is *this* a sufficient explanation?

My goal with this is to know what is an appropriate way a company can direct some users to know A) Stack Overflow exists to answer programming questions and B) A tag exists regarding Keen IO and your question may have already been answered there.  I would like to ensure this is done in a way that is considered appropriate by the MSO community.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/product-support-redirects-to-stack-overflow and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261202/578411 and in the help center [our model](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: From what I've read from those links, it looks like Keen IO is doing about 90% of that.  The only piece they're missing is emphasizing what is not on-topic.

Comment: *Stack Overflow exists to answer programming questions* Would be nice if you included that detail in the quoted descriptions ;)

Comment: the SO logo is wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate @KevinB?

Comment: the new logo has 5 bars, not 6. :)

Comment: Puntip: `Does Keen IO Link to Stack Overflow too Keenly?`

Comment: @BlackVegetable The logo was redesigned relatively recently, likely the icon used here is the older version.

Comment: Besides the misuse of the Stack Overflow logo & name, I'd say it's fine.

Comment: I will self-answer this once I bring this up with the Community team at Keen IO.  If they decide they'll change the logo and\or add the detail mentioned by Will, I'll answer with that information once it is done. On the off-chance they decide to take no action, I'll respond with that information as soon as I know.  Thank you all!

Comment: SO logo is wrong and the legal name is 'Stack Overflow', not 'StackOverflow'.